# appendTo erasing after page reload

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a grocery list with jquery here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.project-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var project = $('.project-val').val();

    $('<li></li>').addClass(project).text(project).appendTo('.project-list');

});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DQxE7/

Everything works fine except that what ever I append doesn't save. As in when I reload the page what ever was added to the ul gets erased how can I prevent that?

Comment: HTML is stateless. Use some storage mechanism to persist.

Comment: Where do you think it should be stored?

Comment: @zerkms I just want it to be added to the html not stored in a cookie or local storage If anyone else goes on the website I want them to be able to see whats been appended

Comment: @swsa That is where a server-side comes into picture...?

Comment: You need to store changes (to the HTML) somewhere other than client side; e.g. server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that everything (including the html and the code) will simply be executed again and reloaded (so what is stored on the server or what was sent with the response stays the same) when the page is refreshed.

You will need to store your data in a data store somewhere (e.g. database), and in your script a functionality that

- upon reload will get the data from the database and add it to your html
- on click add on both the database and the html.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I thought there might be a pre-made jquery function that someway save the html but what you said makes sense and how I will go about it thanks!

Comment: @swsa jquery/javascript runs on the client.

Comment: If you're familiar with JavaScript, you can look at node.js as a server side solution that could hook itself with Java Script. You may also look at Java Spring, Python Django, C# .Net and Ruby on Rails for web  solutions among others.